# Will turning off htaccess have a noticable performance increase?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, debian, virtualhost

Will turning off override by htaccess in apache have a performance increase? I have had a look online and there is very little articles/reports on this.

If this is the case how do I go about turning this off? Will I do this in the default virtual host file?

A example being:
OpenCart comes with 2 htaccess files mainly for mod_rewrite, if I move this into a `<Directory>` will this make a difference?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin www@shop.co.uk
    ServerName shop.co.uk
    ServerAlias www.shop.co.uk
    DocumentRoot /var/www/shop/public

    <Directory /var/www/shop/public>
        Options +FollowSymlinks

        # Prevent Direct Access to files
        <FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
         Order deny,allow
         Deny from all
        </FilesMatch>

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/shop/public/admin/view/javascript/ckeditor>
        AddType application/x-javascript .js
        AddType text/css .css

        # If PHP is mapped to handle XML files, you could have some issues. The following will disable it.
        AddType text/xml .xml
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/shop-error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/shop-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apache won't need to look for a .htaccess file every time it accesses a file.  The actual performance benefit will depend on,

1. traffic to your site
2. site layout
3. server profile

I suggest you baseline the existing performance, using a web stress tool such as Apache's `ab`, make the change, re-profile, and see how much impact it has.

As to your second question, yes, I believe you would move the .htaccess stuff into `<Directory>` sections in your `<VirtualHost>`.

Comment: Another thing to note is it'll search every parent directory for an `.htaccess` file - deeper directories mean more checks (on every request).  `AllowOverride None` to disable completely.

Comment: As an alternative to *ab* you might use http://www.joedog.org/index/siege-home